# Firebase/Javascript signInWithEmailAndPassword failed to fetch resource (server responded with 400)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

While trying to log in a user with Firebase's log in with email and password, this error occurs:
`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyCgebjp9UWGlH-gMBp0MVYJ8thoXqglt-Q`
 `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`

Here is my code:

```js
import {initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js"
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-auth.js"
import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-database.js"

const firebaseConfig = {
    // config is correct, removed for sake of privacy
  };

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase();
const auth = getAuth();

function Login() {
    // this part returns the error
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, $("#email").val(), $("#password").val())
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the actual response text (use your dev-tools _Network_ panel)?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Comment: No, the actual response text / body. Find the request in your _Network_ list, click it and and open the _Response_ tab

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_EMAIL",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: So it's saying you're not sending a valid email. Have you tried debugging the values you're sending?

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't realize it was an input error. Thanks